# GNOME propagate key event after handling them

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 20.04, keyboard-layout

I run Ubuntu 20.04 with GNOME 3.36.2.
I have set switching keyboard layout to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Alt</kbd>:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Shift>Alt_L']"
```

However, Slack uses <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>arrow up</kbd>/<kbd>arrow down</kbd> to go to next unread channel. Apparently, GNOME intercepts these keys first, changes keyboard layout and does not let Slack handle them as well.

Is it possible to make GNOME propagate these keys further to other applications?

I want to keep the shortcut the same for both things. It worked well on Unity with Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: shift arrowup/down alt?? whats the result?

Comment: You can probably use <Alt><Shift><arrow> (i.e. <Alt> before <Shift>) in Slack.